# tensorflow issue with image reading

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I am following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) example to read an image (from my disk) with tensorflow:

```py
img_raw = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
img_tensor = tf.image.decode_image(img_raw)

print(repr(img_raw))
print(img_tensor.shape)
print(img_tensor.dtype)
```

but the **shape** is coming as unknown:

```
<tf.Tensor 'ReadFile_4:0' shape=() dtype=string>
<unknown>
<dtype: 'uint8'>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled eager execution? It could be the case that TF isn't reading the image since eager execution is not enabled.

Comment: well I added the statement, but missed to execute it :D 
Thanks @hssay

Comment: Great! Can you add an answer yourself and close it? It can help others with similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tensorflow 1.x we need to execute

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

to see results before creating a tf session.

For tf 2.x eager execution is enabled by default.